# how to convert mysql queries to microsoft sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some MySQL queries that I want to transform to MS SQL.

```
$result_of_sql_query = mysql_query( $settings['query'] , $settings['connect'] );
```

How do I transform this to MS SQL Server query.

Comment: Can you add the query itself?

Comment: I recommend not taking any shortcuts.   Take the time to learn TSQL and re-write the queries yourself.   Owning code that you don't know how to maintain is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `Statement` and pasting the above query into the Query Browser. From here, you could right click on the Statement and '`Convert Schema`'

Comment: the convert schema is disabled.you re talking about using ssma right

Comment: Please see the comment I've posted to @ProblemSolver. This contains the link you can follow to achieve the Convert Schema.

In future, try to be more specific in your question: See this link to aid in asking a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask